# In java what does 'for(int something : something else)' mean?

Tags: java

My teachers said this will be on the ap test and I have no idea what it means. Please help!

Comment: See also [The `for` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [The For-Each Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Comment: Also, don't be afraid to ask your teachers. It's their job to teach you things you don't know.